# Host with space in hosts file

Tags: windows, hosts

Is it possible to add a host with a space in it to my hosts file in Windows?

Like 192.168.1.2 My%20Host

Note that %20 doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible, the name of hosts may not contain space. http://compnetworking.about.com/od/windowsnetworking/qt/wcomputernaming.htm

Comment: While your answer ("No") is correct, your reasoning is wrong. The host name may not contain spaces because RFC 952 says _"up to 24 characters drawn from the alphabet (A-Z), digits (0-9), minus sign (-), and period (.)"_.